# Error message if IIS 5.1 is stopped?

Tags: php, asp.net, internet-explorer, iis

Is there a way to show any error message if IIS(5.1) is stopped or not working? We have got few websites on server 2000 and we want to show some message to end user if IIS doesn't respond due to any reasons.

I have tested this scenario on the test server, i just stopped the IIS and then try to access one of the website to see if i get any error message from IIS but i didn't get any IIS error message (IE: Internet Explorer cannot display the webpage)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since IIS is *the web server* that receives HTTP requests and responds to them, you'd need to run *another* web server that does the same thing instead of IIS. If you're running a web server that can respond to HTTP requests with an error message though, you may as well use it to run your website. In short, unless you have another system sitting in front of your actual web server that can detect when the web server is down (say, a load balancer)... it's kind of an unrealistic proposal.